# Using Volume Shadow Copy Service OK for backing up SQL Server Compact?

Tags: sql-server-ce, volume-shadow-service

Would one expect a backup of a SQL Server Compact database file created with Volume Shadow Copy Service expected to be consistent?  I know the big SQL Server has a VSS writer to ensure consistency.  If a connection is writing out to a SQL Server Compact database could the file be backed up in a inconsistent state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

backup files are called "crash-consistent" when there is no writer service. you may be missing the recent updates, but usually good. ofcourse, depends on how critical your data or application is.

Comment: So, I suppose since SQL CE is in-process, my own application would have to act as the writer service by receiving notification that a backup is about to occur.

Comment: It would have to, not sure the SQL CE code will do that automatically for you. Did you manage to find an answer here?